# Why are dependency graphs not represented as bi-directional acyclic graphs?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, dependencies

I know that dependency graphs (say to figure out which package depends on which packages during installations) can be represented as directed acyclic graphs.

```
a
|--> b
|    |--> d
|    `--> e
|         |
|         |
`--> c <--'
```

For example, the above graph represents the following.

- a depends on b, c, d, e
- b depends on d, e, c
- c depends on nothing
- d depends on nothing
- e depends on c

This graph can help us answer what a certain package depends on in linear time, i.e. O(n) where n is the total number of packages and edges in the graph. Example: Which packages a depends on? The result is: b, c, d, e.

It can help us answer simple question like what a certain package immediately depends on in constant time. Example: Which packages a immediately depends on? The result is: b, c.

But it cannot answer a simple question like what immediately depends on a certain package in constant time. Example: Which packages immediately depend on c? The result is: a and e. To answer this simple question seems to require a complete search of the graph thereby requiring linear time. This can be improved if each child vertex keeps a backlink to its parent vertex while still maintaining the distinction between child and parent.

If we introduce backlinks from each child vertix to its parent, it becomes a bidirectional acyclic graph, and it seems to simplify many graph search algorithms.

I have the following questions.

1. Is there a formal name for such dependencies graphs?
2. Why do we not see bidirectional acyclic graphs in the study of computational theory often?
3. Are such bidirectional graphs used in actual implementations of dependency graphs? Examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add back-links that have no semantic meaning and only speeds up the "who refers to me" search, that's still a DAG. In the same way, parent links in search trees don't turn the trees into search "graphs". It's an implementation detail of no semantic or mathematical significance. Hence it's not studied separately (at most, given a off-hand mention when discussing complexity).

Also, people are flexible which way the edges go anyway (dependency -> user or user -> dependency), both are used depending on what is needed. I can't think of many use cases that need both in the same graph. And even then, it may be more profitable to just invert the edges of the whole graph (single O(n) operation) when needed.

For these reasons, this optimization is not usually given a separate name. It's just "a DAG", one "(with backedges)" if it's important to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that you're talking about here (generating all edges like a->c when a->b and b->c) is called a [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure). It is itself useful, interesting and studied. However, storing all such edges explicitly will result in a (potentially quadratic) blowup of the storage space required for the graph, because in a complete graph with *|V|* nodes you have *O(|V|<sup>2</sup>)* edges. So this is a trade-off between space and time complexity: if you store all the (forward) edges you can traverse the graph (forward) much more quickly, in constant time as you observed, but you pay the price in storage.

Although you didn't ask about this, I'll point out that storing the transitive closure explicitly is probably undesirable for dependency graphs. Take for instance a package manager: you want it to find out quickly the immediate dependencies in order to check if they are installed and if they are not perhaps to add the missing ones to a transaction installing multiple packages. But enabling constant time access to all (direct and indirect) dependencies of a package doesn't seem particularly useful in this context because most of the indirect dependencies are likely to be satisfied anyway. You'd just get a much larger list to go over and probably conclude that most are installed anyway.

---

The other thing that you're talking about, i.e the graph with every edge reversed, is called the [transpose graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_graph). Note that you need to [bi]color the edges (use differently named member pointer/references) if you store both the "direct" and the transpose graph in the same data structure. Storing them together this way is rather trivial so I guess that's why you don't see much mention of it. Some graph algorithm works/books [do assume](https://books.google.com/books?id=kcCrBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA12) such a representation for directed graphs, i.e. that both the incoming and outgoing edges are stored in separate (doubly linked) lists for each vertex. Although many (introductory) textbooks indeed don't talk about it (presumably in order to keep their presentation simple), this representation (i.e. with both incoming and outgoing lists) [is used in practice, for example in LEDA](https://books.google.com/books?id=NSfIWxqPlbcC&pg=PA41). Here's a slide from [a LEDA presentation](ftp://ftp.mpi-inf.mpg.de/pub/conferences/adfocs03/Slides/Naeher_2.pdf) detailing their static (i.e. assumed fixed) graph data structures; the dynamic one would have doubly-linked lists instead of arrays. I'm including both the unidirectional ("directed") and their "bidirectional" representation for easy comparison:

[image]

Boost has a similar feature, although it is just a tweak (called `bidirectionalS`) for their [adjacency list implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html):

> The bidirectionalS selector specifies that the graph will provide the in_edges() function as well as the out_edges() function. This imposes twice as much space overhead per edge, which is why in_edges() is optional.

Keep in mind that because you can tell apart the two sets of edges (via "first in" and "first out" in the case of LEDA or in_edges() and out_edges in the case of boost) what you really have here is a mathematically a [disjoint union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union) of a directed graph with its transpose. If you lose the distinction/color between the two sets of edges (pointers), what you get is sometimes called a *bidirected graph*, although the term (like alas many in graph theory) [is unfortunately overloaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirected_graph). And if you had hopes that LEDA's term *bidirectional graph* is somehow standardized with their meaning, it's actually [more likely to mean the same thing as bidirected graph to theorists](https://books.google.com/books?id=RBBOarefKC8C&pg=PA87).

So to summarize my answer so far:

1. I don't think there's a name for the a dependecy graph stored like this, but for graphs in general bidirectional representation would be resonable name, which unfortunately doesn't appear as such outside of a few software packages. Bidirected (or bidirectional) graph is a more widespread term,  but most theorist will probably think you mean you can no longer can tell the difference between the two sets of edges (i.e. they'll assume you mean union instead of disjoint union with the transpose graph.)
2. It seems it is mostly an aspect discussed in practical implementation contexts (like LEDA or boost) so theory and intro books seem to not care much about it.

As for practical representations of package repositories (3), you seem to ignore that most (that I know of) will store AND, OR and NOT constraints to additionally handle alternatives and conflicts. You can only handle AND with a dependency graph like we discussed above. Once you add those additional OR & NOT features you get to solve much harder (NP-complete) [SAT problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) just to install something; see [the Opium paper](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~lerner/papers/opium.pdf) (2007) for a discussion; for a more recent one (2010) see the [Apt-pbo paper](http://www.mancoosi.org/papers/ase10.pdf). So constant-time reverse dependency look-ups start to seem like a trifle in comparison. But to actually answer your question:

3. I've looked at the apt sources and it does store the reverse dependencies separately in its cache (which you [query with `apt-cache`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/apt-cache.8.html)). For each package (`pkgCache::Package` defined in `pkgcache.h`) there's a [`RevDepends` linked list](https://alioth.debian.org/plugins/scmgit/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=apt/apt.git;a=blob;f=apt-pkg/pkgcache.h;h=5e8a9630a0b190afe2f82b1321ba96e6110c9ece;hb=19853c18629bf531b913255905e5727ae2c33bb0#l392) and apt updates it every time you install or remove something: in [`depcache.cc`:`pkgDepCache::Update`](https://alioth.debian.org/plugins/scmgit/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=apt/apt.git;a=blob;f=apt-pkg/depcache.cc;h=16282df2135e358c9917139737527cffdd4f30d4;hb=19853c18629bf531b913255905e5727ae2c33bb0#l736) it has for loop that does (among other things) an `Update(P.ParentPkg().RevDependsList());`.